# Blender Color Ramp in dark environment

Tags: shaders, eevee-render-engine, shader-nodes

I have a scene where all objects have a color ramp node. When I turn off light, HDRIs, world color, and so on, I still see objects in color. I want that when all lights are off and I render the image, to not see nothing in render.
The scene is a night club and only lights I want to see are the ones I made, everything else should be in dark or close to.

As you can see in picture. There are 2 cubes. The blue cube has a color ramp and it renders blue. There is one more cube between the blue cube and my scene that doesnt have color ramp and in render you can not see it. I want to achieve the same thing for my other objects and make only my lights shine on them[image] and give them color and visibility.

This is Node tree for pretty much every object. I'm using Eevee.

[image]

Comment: When you think it has something to do with the _Color Ramp_ node, would it be too much to ask that you also show us the shader nodetree of at least one of those materials so that we can see if there is something causing this behaviour? And maybe you could also tell us if you are using _Cycles_ or _Eevee_ (although I think it's not essential in this case)? But if you are not using a very very old version, this is surely not the old Blender Internal render engine which you have put in the tags.

Comment: You need to put a shader (Diffuse or Principled BSDF) just before the Output, otherwise the image or the ColorRamp will be emissive, I guess this is your problem here but as Gordon says it would be useful to see a screenshot of your Shader Editor

Comment: Please show your shader node-trees

Comment: For sure. Node tree added. This is node tree for pretty much every element in the picture. If I remove color ramp I think it works ok. Im using Eevee. Blender version 3.5.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann not sure about the tags. Just started with Blender not to long ago. Stack overflow gave me very few tags to choose from to put.

Comment: As @moonboots said, you need to plug that color data into a shader node before instead of the material output. Any color data plugged in the material output is treated as an emission (raw color only) shader. You can use a simple diffuse shader or a principled, it doesn't matter. Also for simplicity and performance sake, you probably don't need a principled shader plugged into your shader to rgb node, I bet you don't use any of these settings aside the color, a diffuse shader there would be simpler and tidier.

Comment: The reason "color ramp" **seems** to be an issue is that it doesn't go from black to whatever color, it starts at a somewhat bright color, so when there's no light, the "shader to RGB" generates black, but then it's translated to non-black by the color ramp. BTW, "Color Ramp" has been renamed and since B3.6 has a space between "color" and "ramp" in its name.

Comment: Thanks guys. Putting Difuse before the output did the trick. @moonboots is you wanna put the answer with a bit of explanation so I accept it as a solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put a shader (*Diffuse* or *Principled BSDF*) just before the *Output*, otherwise the image or the *ColorRamp* will be emissive.